# Best practice for validators in Django serializers?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am currently new to DRF, working on validators for a "Book Edition" serializer. They seem to be working as intended, but as I am looking into documentation it seems most people override the validate() or include them in the Meta class. I am wondering if I am going about this completely wrong now!
My main questions are:

1. Is it appropriate to add these validators through the serializers.IntegerField()s?
2. Will both these validators for the ISBN be called when the data is serialized?

Here is my code:

```
class EditionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ISBN = serializers.IntegerField(
        validators=[
            UniqueValidator(
                queryset=Edition.objects.all(), message="ISBN must be unique."
            ),
        ],
    )

    def validate_ISBN(self, value):
        errors = {}
        if len(str(value)) != 10 and len(str(value)) != 13:
            errors[
                "digits"
            ] = "A valid ISBN number must contain either 10 or 13 digits."
        if errors:
            raise ValidationError(errors)
        return value

    year_published = serializers.IntegerField(
        validators=[MaxValueValidator(limit_value=timezone.now().year)]
    )
```

Comment: Using an `IntegerField` and serializing by length will not work, if you enter `0002`, it will produce `2`, so `len(str(value))` will be one, even if you wrote `0002`. This is not a problem for ISBN-13 since it starts with 978 (which is "bookland" in the EAN standard), but for ISBN-10, it is.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Thanks for pointing that out- would a CharField be a better option here, perhaps?

Comment: All validators will be called.  Validators on the field will be called first, then in the `validate_{field}` function, then the root `validate(self, attrs)`.  Method validators can't modify the value, but serializer validators can return a new/modified value. https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/#limitations-of-validators

Comment: There isn't a write (ha!) way to do it, they all work.  I prefer defining the validators in the field if it's pure value validation, but otherwise in `validate_field`, and only use validate(attrs) when things need to be combined.  I rarely find those validations can be re-used so I see now value in hiding them outside the immediate area unless they get too big.